# How to get the difference between columns within group in R?

Tags: r

I have this dataframe called `mydf`. There dataframe is separated into each group by a row called `myid`. So, I want to get the difference of two values (modulas) between two columns of row `CDS` and get the result as shown below.

```
mydf<- structure(list(c("myid:AHY03257.1", "176", "myid:YP_009182164.1", 
"308", "myid:YP_717161.1", "9801", "8391", "8060"), c(NA, 2605L, 
NA, 2443L, NA, 9659L, 8029L, 8407L), c("", "CDS", "", "CDS", 
"", "CDS", "CDS", "CDS")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

result:

```
myid:AHY03257.1               
                 176 2605 CDS   2429
myid:YP_009182164.1      
                 308 2443 CDS   2135
myid:YP_717161.1       
                9801 9659 CDS   142
                8391 8029 CDS   362
                8060 8407 CDS   347
```

Comment: Isn't there any column names/

Comment: There are three columns basically.

Comment: `myid` row separates the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `tidyverse`.  After setting column names to the dataset, group by the cumulative sum of logical vector (`str_detect`) based on the occurence of `:` in the first column, remove the first observation from 'V1', convert it to `numeric` and get the absolute difference with the 'V2' column

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>% 
   set_names(paste0('V', seq_along(.))) %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(V1, ":"))) %>%
   mutate(V4 = abs(V2 - c(NA, as.numeric(V1[-1])))) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp) %>%
   set_names(rep("", 4)) # better to have column name, removed to match input data
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#  ``                     `` ``       ``
#  <chr>               <int> <chr> <dbl>
#1 myid:AHY03257.1        NA ""       NA
#2 176                  2605 CDS    2429
#3 myid:YP_009182164.1    NA ""       NA
#4 308                  2443 CDS    2135
#5 myid:YP_717161.1       NA ""       NA
#6 9801                 9659 CDS     142
#7 8391                 8029 CDS     362
#8 8060                 8407 CDS     347
```

---

However, if a warning message is okay, then we can directly convert the `character` column 'V1' into `numeric` (gives a warning as there are non-numeric elements - which gets convert to `NA`) and do the absolute difference with the 'V2' column

```
mydf %>% 
  set_names(paste0("V", seq_along(.))) %>%
  mutate(V4 = abs(V2 - as.numeric(V1)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me re-order that kinda dataset that you have create:

```
mydf <- data.frame(mydf= 
c("AHY03257.1","YP_009182164.1","YP_717161.1","YP_717161.1","YP_717161.1"),value_1= 
c(176,308,9801,8391,8060),value_2=c(2605,2443,9659,8029,8407),CDS=rep("CDS",5))
```

then, you have to create a new column:

```
mydf$abs_diff <- abs(mydf$value_2 - mydf$value_1)
```